# DB Server location in relation to main Web Server

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2008-r2, vps, web-hosting

Ive recently taken the plunge and started renting a VPS for my web projects. As the demands on the system get higher so do the costs. MY VPS is US based due to costs, but Im based in Germany.

Initially I decided I'd try and run everything on a Windows 2008 VPS: .net, SQLServer. Then I added php and MySQL, and the server is now reaching 80% memory usage(2GB).

The costs of upgrading would appear to be higher than getting some 3rd party hosting for the MySQL and sheds some of the strain from the VPS. This raises 2 questions:

1) Is it better to have the DB Server located near the server, for improved transaction times? Or is it better to have the DB hosted nearer to Europe for delivery to the end user?

2) The DB server is likely to be some mass hosting solution inorder to keep costs to a minimum. Would this likely be an improvement or degradation compared to running on a Win Server with 80% memory use?

Obviously I have my own somewhat unsubstantiated ideas, but would love to get some insight from those with more practical knowledge than myself.

P.s. Ive currently no seriously intensive applications/sites running on the server at this time.

Comment: WTF??? A down vote and not even a comment as to why!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want the SQL server to be as close as possible to your current VPS; preferably in the same datacenter for best results. It doesn't matter where it is for end-users because it should be your website accessing the database and not the users.

Comment: Hi Nathan, thats what I assumed but wanted to be 100% since I'd had comments to the contrary elsewhere. Thanks for answering.

Comment: running the server at 80% is fine unless you are expecting a lot of growth.  Once you get to 80% it's time to consider adding RAM but is shouldn't impact performance unless you're seeing lots of page faults. Look at what processes are using RAM.  If you have sql server installed consider migrating everything to that instance (or MySQL presuming MySQL has the features you need) sql server is designed to do it's own memory optimization so you often see high memory utilization on systems with sql but that can be set to a fixed size and generally doesn't hurt other application performance.